# Bootstrap model showing me first row data every time

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, web

Bootstrap model showing me same data in `while` loop. When I click any model it shows me first row data, how to fix this please help me.

Here is code

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_store order by store_id DESC";
  $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     #code here
  }
```

HTML code

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle;">
  <a href="#myModal1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Edit</button>
  </a>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel1">Edit Store</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form role="form" action="editStore.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- text input -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" style="text-align:right; color:#000000;">
                <h6>Store Name :</h6>
                <br>
                <h6 style="margin-bottom:40px; margin-top:-10px;">Description:</h6> 
                <br>
                <h6>Phone:</h6>
                <br>
                <h6 style="margin-top:0px;">Address:</h6>
                <br>
                <h6 style="margin-top:0px;">Latitude:</h6>
                <br>
                <h6 style="margin-top:0px;">Longitude:</h6>
                <br>
                <h6 style="margin-top:0px;">City:</h6>
                <br>
                <h6 style="margin-top:0px;">Country:</h6>
                <br>
                <h6 style="margin-top:0px;">Upload photo:</h6>
                <p style="color:red;">*If you want to replace</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9" style="text-align:left; color:#000000;">
                <input type="text" class="input form-control" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:10px;" name="title" value="<?php echo $row['store_title']; ?>" required/> 
                <br>
                <textarea class="input input-group" rows="3" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:10px; padding-left:10px;" name="description" required><?php echo $row['store_description']; ?></textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:10px;" name="phone" value="<?php echo $row['store_phone']; ?>"/>
                <br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:10px;" name="address" value="<?php echo $row['store_address']; ?>" required/>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 pull-left">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:10px;" max="180" min="0" step="0.00001" name="lat" value="<?php echo $row['store_lat']; ?>" required/>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:10px;" max="180" min="0" step="0.00001" name="long" value="<?php echo $row['store_long']; ?>" required/>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:10px;" name="city" value="<?php echo $row['store_city']; ?>" required/>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:10px;" name="country" value="<?php echo $row['store_country']; ?>" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 pull-right">
                          <img src="<?php echo $row['store_image'];?>" style="float:right;max-height:200px;max-width:200px;">
                        </div>
                        <input type="file"  style="margin-left:15px; width:93%;" name="photo"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="store_id" value="<?php echo $row['store_id'];?>">
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Save changes</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: the html code for the display must go inside the `while` brackets `{ }` otherwhise the loop runs and when you try to access the `$row` var after that, it contains the last iterated row

Comment: i have tried this also, but same result. and try with get variable method and fetch data again but problem still remains :(

Comment: what is a bootstrap model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while Looping your Target has to be unique set of id which equals to id="myModal1". eg.

```
    //inside while loop
  target="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" and id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>
```

Comment: Mark his answer as correct, you would be returning the favor!

Comment: target means data-target? and id means data-id?